# In Gtk#, how do I get a Window's AccelGroup?

Tags: c#, gtk, gtk#

The constructor for a stock ImageMenuItem requires an AccelGroup. I think I should use the main Window's AccelGroup, but I'm not sure how to get it.

Edit: It turns out you can use the `Stock` Enum in `ImageMenuItem (string label)`, not just in `ImageMenuItem (string stockId, AccelGroup accelGroup)`. So I don't really need to get the Window's AccelGroup after all. Still, it would be nice to know for future reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **[Accel](http://www.go-mono.com/docs/index.aspx?link=T:Gtk.Accel/*)** class

```
AccelGroup glist[] = Accel.GroupsFromObject(mywindow);
```

Comment: I accepted this because it answered the question that I asked, but I ended up just doing `new ImageMenuItem (stockId, null)`.